# React context error with nested components (childrens) in react-shuffle

Tags: reactjs

I've some problems because reactjs loose the context when you use children components, in my case I've to pass a baobab tree in the context (is the way how baobab works so I don't have other choice)

```
render(){
  return(
    <Shuffle>
       <ComponentA/> //these components loose the context
       <ComponentA/>
       <ComponentA/>
     </Shuffle>)
}
```

in the baobab repository I get a possible [solution](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab-react/issues/52)

but looking the  reaact-shuffle code seems than it's already using cloneWithProps (which btw will be deprecated)

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-shuffle/blob/master/src/shuffle.js#L256
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-shuffle/blob/master/src/shuffle.js#L115

this lib is a bit different to the most of react components than I've watched before and [many](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-shuffle/blob/master/src/shuffle.js#L238-L251) piece of [code](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-shuffle/blob/master/src/shuffle.js#L16-L27) are not so clear to me..

I'll appreciate any help, thank so much